# Having trouble getting Jest to work with API. Jest cannot recognized config file

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

Jest is trying to run through the complete file rather than a specific function.

I tried destructuring the function with still no luck.

authController.js

```
const {
    login
} = require('../authController');

it('Should authenticate users', () => {
    expect(login()).toBe(3)
});
```

expected results:

```
Should authenticate users...
```

actual results:

```
Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'authenticationHost' of undefined

      4 | const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
      5 | const config = require('../config/config.json');
    > 6 | const authenticationHost = config[env].authenticationHost;
        |                                        ^
      7 | const loginRoute = authenticationHost+config.default.loginRoute;
      8 | const touchLoginRoute = authenticationHost+config.default.touchLoginRoute;
      9 | const {getCurrentDateTimeOffset} = require(`${__basedir}/utils/dateAndTime`);

      at Object.authenticationHost (controllers/authController.js:6:40)
      at Object.require (controllers/__test__/authController.test.js:3:5)
```

The thing is when we run our endpoints against Postman they work fine.

Why is jest trying to run everything in the file? What is the solution?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? It has to execute everything at the top level of the module to import it.

Comment: The thing is when we run our endpoints against Postman they work fine. I thought by destructuring the function from the file I could prevent this.

Comment: Maybe your test environment is different with your local development environment. That's why jest failed, but postman works fine. Can't help without further info.